# JPA Entity CRUD type Operations support in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

Due to some odd reason, I cannot go with JPA vendor like Hibernate, etc and **I must use MyBatis.**

Is there any implementation where we can enrich similar facility of CRUD operation in Mybatis?
(Like  GenericDAO save, persist, merge, etc)

I have managed to come up with single interface implementation of CRUD type of operations (like Generic DAO) but still each table has to write it's own query in XML file (as table name, column names are different).

Will that make sense to come up with generic implementation?
Where I can give any table object for any CRUD operation through only 4 XML queries. (insert, update, read, delete) passing arguments of table name, column names, column values..etc.

Does it look like re-inventing the wheel in MyBatis or does MyBatis has some similar support?

Answer (score 0):

you can try Mybatis Plus.This is for these cases.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can refer me some reference link of the same.

Answer (score 0):

MyBatis is not an ORM, instead it maps the result from SQL statements to objects.

You need to write SQL.

You will have a hard time if you try and apply the JPA model to working in MyBatis. You need to learn how MyBatis works instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the MyBatis Generator. Here is a screenshot of the introduction paragraph.

[image]

And here is the [URL](https://mybatis.org/generator/).

The generator looks at the Physical tables in an RDBMS and generates the CRUD mapping.That is half the job done. The other half is to utilize these mappings in your actual code.

Let this assumption also be cleared. The generator generates only the CRUD. For more complex operations like aggregations or joins et al, you may need to write the mappers on your own.